# Why are my vertices not following the bone? Weight Paint

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I am new to blender. In the Weight Paint Mode, When I am assigning weight to vertices they are changing and becoming stringy when I move rotate the shoulder bone. I'm not quite sure what is going on. How can I solve this problem? [Video to show what is going on](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ebsm8o8bs58t40/2022-11-06%2021-55-54.mp4?dl=0)[Link to download blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9q7qfm5pwycf8sz/roboscientist.blend?dl=0)

Comment: With the pose bone selected in Weight Paint mode, go to *Weights > Clean* and set the threshold to something low like .01 or .05. That will remove all vertices assigned to this bone that have a weight less than that amount. I think this will solve your issue here.

Comment: I figured out why it wasn't working, another bone (foot) had weight paint on the the forearm. Thank you to those who responded to my question.